# Visual studio code user snippets not working for php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Visual studio code user snippets not working for php. Have restarted VS code and the PC. Still does not work.

**User snippet code**:

[image]

**No snippet shows up**:

[image]

**Visual studio code version**:

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please share all details in text form, not hidden in screenshots

Answer (score 12):

Put it in the `html` snippets file. It is what `php` files use unless you are inside `<?php ?>` tags.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know  VSC won't pick up your php snippets even though your file might end in .php , what you have to do is insert manually `<? php ... ?>` and afterwards your snippets should start work.

If you don't want to enter `<? php ... ?>` manually every time you can create a global snippet "Preferences-->User Snippets-->New Global Snippets File. Save the new file to something like "global.code-snippets" and then add your php snippet. 
Maybe something like that.

```
"php tag": {
"prefix": "php",
"body": [
  "<?php",
  "  ${1:code}",
  "?>"
],
"description": "php tag"}
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I created a snippet: 
 "PHP envelope": {
  "prefix": "php",
  "body": "<?php $0 ?>",
  "description": "Enter PHP mode."
 }
that wouldn't work in php.json but now works in global snippets.

Comment: Perfect, I had the same problem. I didn't know about global snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring Visual Studio Code for PHP development from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/):

- Download and install [PHP Debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) from Visual Studio marketplace.
- In VS Code command panel: press <kbd>F1</kbd> > type ‘install ext’ and select ‘Install Extensions’.
  [image]